# An error in localizable.strings file in Xcode 12 in English Localization

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have two localizations in my app one for Arabic and one for English but in English localization only first keys are being read from Xcode but latest aren't localized.
I know it may be a syntax error but I can't find it because the file is large and I tried to find semicolon number and `"="` number and they are equal;
Is there any way to find where is the error exactly?
may be a site or tool that could help me.

Answer (score 0):

check if one of your `"`may be replaced by `'` or maybe missed.

try the search with: `'`, `'=`, `='`, and `';`.

note: if you add a space before and after `=` then consider it in your search.